# How do I change the favicon in google's "web starter kit?"

Tags: web, favicon, material-design-lite

I replaced all of the files in images/touch with my own logo, and also replaced favicon.ico in the main directory of my project, but the favicon still displays as the default asterisk that comes with web starter kit. I tried refreshing the cache of my browser, and adding in

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://mywebsite.com/app/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

to try and manually link the favicon. This works, only when

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png">
```

is also commented out. But this will change the behavior of chrome for Android so that it is incorrect. Also, "images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png" has been replaced with *MY* icon now, so why does this line make the favicon revert back?

Comment: Apparently some of your text is missing ("only when..." what? :) ). You should edit your question.

Comment: Is `http://mywebsite.com/app/favicon.ico?v=2` a valid path for your project? It should be `http://mywebsite.com/favicon.ico?v=2` with a regular GWSK project (the content of `app` is mounted at the root). That might explain why you `favicon.ico` declaration attempt didn't work.

Comment: It is the correct path. I tried both. Without /app it doesn't show up ever. With it, only when the chrome icon is commented out. My biggest concern is that there are no asterisk images in my project but it keeps appearing, soI don't know where it's coming from. My question really boils down to: does web starter kit come with .js/.css that overrides the favicon? where? and how does that chrome icon line trigger it?

Comment: This really sounds like a caching issue, even if you took care of this. Note that the 192x192 PNG icon won't confuse Android Chrome: recent versions will pick the icons of manifest.json, as expected. As an alternative, you can also try this:  http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon/google_web_starter_kit (disclamer: I'm the author of this service).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem after I replace following files with my own image:

1. /app/favicon.ico
2. /app/images/touch/apple-touch-icon.png
3. /app/images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png
4. /app/images/touch/icon-128x128.png
5. /app/images/touch/ms-icon-144x144.png
6. /app/images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png

Problem was solved when I close and open again my browser.